# Adding another CSS id to jQuery Function

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I am successfully using this code to fade in/out my menu id `#shiftnav-toggle-main` during scrolling. I am looking to incorporate another id, e.g. `#side-toggle` to my function, but I am not sure if there is a better way of doing this, without duplicating all of my code for the new id.

```
var menu = jQuery("#shiftnav-toggle-main");
var opacity = menu.css("opacity");
var scrollStopped;
var fadeInCallback = function () {
    if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(scrollStopped);
    }
    scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
        menu.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
    }, 500);
};
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
     if (!menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
     menu.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
     } else {
         fadeInCallback.call(this);
     }
});
```

Comment: you can try using `jQuery("#shiftnav-toggle-main,#side-toggle");`

Comment: Sletheren, I can't add classes bcs I am referencing to external plugins.. Chirag, I tried that already but didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that handles the mechanism:

```
let scrollStopped;

let fadeInCallback = function() {
  if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
    clearInterval(scrollStopped);
  }
  scrollStopped = setTimeout(function() {
    menu.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, "slow");
  }, 500);
};

let handleScrollFade = function(id) {
  let menu = $(id);
  let opacity = menu.css("opacity");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
      menu.animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
    } else {
      fadeInCallback.call(this);
    }
  });

}

handleScrollFade('#shiftnav-toggle-main');
handleScrollFade('#side-toggle');
```

Comment: Ivan would this work if the #side-toggle is loaded as an iframe? <iframe id="side-toggle" .... >

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Not sure but I think it should work.. you want the iframe to fade when scrolling?

Comment: yes that's what I am looking for.. I need to modify your function for strict mode and then I will test it.